# Rails batch select on multi column index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to get the query syntax down in Rails for doing a command like:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE (colA = aaa AND colB = bbb) OR (colA = ccc AND colB = ddd) OR ...

Where I would have 100+ of these queries hitting a composite index and each value of colA and colB is unique.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have tried and how it didn't work as planned?

Comment: The basic way is to do `Table.where(id: 1, name: '').or(Table.where(id: 2, name: ''))`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  def self.matching_conditons(conditions)
    first, *rest = conditions
    rest.inject(where(first)) do |scope, hash|
      scope.or(where(hash))
    end
  end
end
```

Useage:

```
Thing.matching_conditons(
  [{ foo: 1, bar: 'A'}, { foo: 2, bar: 'B'}, { foo: 3, bar: 'C'}]
)
```

This is basically the equivilent to calling:

```
Thing.where( foo: 1, bar: 'A')
  .or(Thing.where(foo: 2, bar: 'B'))
  .or(Thing.where(foo: 3, bar: 'C'))
```